# KUbuntu Screen Edge triggers no action

Tags: kubuntu, kde

on my current install of Kubuntu 14.04 I cannot get Screen Edges working. I activate them the via (System Settings -> WorkSpace Bahavior -> Scrren Edges). After applying the change I get a blue glow on the activiated edge, but no matter what action I select, there is nothing happening.

For the sake of completeness: I am running  64bit version in VirtualBox, which shouldn't matter.

thank's for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have had screen edges that sometimes stops working, don't know whether your issue is related.

For my problem, running the following command in the terminal usually fixes it:

```
kwin --replace &
```

It is important to include the `&`, otherwise the windows will crash when you close the terminal. See

```
kwin --help
```

on exactly what the command does.